# Few errors when attempting to write a script that uploads any data in EC2 Instance to S3 Bucket using BOTO

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, boto, aws-cli, botocore

I have been trying to back up my EC2 Instance to an S3 Bucket but have contentiously come across few errors when I run the file. Most notable error being S3ResponceError: 403 Forbidden

FYI, I am using my aws access key id, access key secret from Rossetahub (Provided by the school)

below is the code I have written

```
import boto
import boto.s3
import os.path
import sys
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '' 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = ''

bucket_name = 'bucketpoly'
sourceDir = 'example_files/'
destDir = 'example_files1/'
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET)
bucket= conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
uploadFileNames = []

for (sourceDir, dirname, filename) in os.walk(sourceDir):
    uploadFileNames.extend(filename)
    break


def percent_cb(complete, total):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()



for filename in uploadFileNames:

    sourcepath = os.path.join(sourceDir + filename)

    destpath = os.path.join(destDir, filename)

    print ('Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % 
           (sourcepath, bucket_name))



print ("singlepart upload")

k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)

k.key = destpath

k.set_contents_from_filename(sourcepath, cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

this is the resulting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/student/Desktop/PROJECT FILES/testing2.py", line 11, in <module>
    bucket= conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 509, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 542, in head_bucket
    raise err
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

what do you think might be the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden caused by insufficient IAM permissions. From the error, IAM user doesn't have Listobject and Listbucket permission.

This is a link you can use to get start with S3 permissions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html